# Moderated Celebrity chat

Tags: chat

I am searching for a moderated celebrity chat. Every week a celebrity from my country will answer questions from users who join the room. I want to have a moderator who will filter those questions and the decide which to show publicly in the chat. Only the moderator must be able to chat with the celebrity. The answers provided from the celebrity will be published to the room

Is there a solution like this? I prefer free by I'd paid too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can have a look at [123flashChat app](http://www.123flashchat.com/moderated-chat.html) which seems to meet all your requirements but its not free. But its quite easy to integrate with your existing infrastructure.

Comment: The site no longer exists.